# How to map OneToOne relations properly?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, hibernate-mapping

I am new to Hibernate and JPA. I have made my research and read the documentations on OnetoOne relations (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html).
I have tried to map it accordingly and besides the documentation, I have searched for solutions in other sources as well but none of them didn't help me. Every time I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: org.example.entity.SalesReps.regionsId
```

I would be glad to receive any additional sources or solutions on my code.

I have two Entities. Accounts and Sales_reps. I want to make OneToOne mapping for sales_rep_id field inside Accounts entity to Sales_reps's id field.

Accounts Entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Table(name ="accounts")
    public class Accounts extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    
        @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private String name;
        @Column(name = "website", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private String website;
        @Column(name = "latitude", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Double lat;
        @Column(name = "longitude", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Double lon;
        @Column(name = "primary_poc", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private String primaryPerson;
    
        @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name="Sales_rep_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private SalesReps SalesReps; 
}
```

Sales_reps Entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "sales_reps")
public class SalesReps extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(name ="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "region_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Regions regionsId;

}
```

I have BaseEntity class for Id reference:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

Any help is valuable, thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in the Sales_Reps class. You have used @OneToMany annotation, but provided an object as a field and not a collection of objects (which is required for @OneToMany mappings). You probably want to use a List or Set. Another problem is that on @OneToMany side of relationship you do not use @JoinColumn, it should be used on the @ManyToOne side of relationship.

Comment: It worked just perfect!!!!! The issue was clear. It was just me who messed up everything. Thank you @przemek